# After subscribe object not displaying

Tags: javascript, angular, object

After the subscription object not displaying.Did I made any mistake

```
this.service.submitGbtForm(formValue)
          .subscribe((status) => {
            let a = status; // a = {submitGbtFrom: 'success'}
            console.log(a, 'SINGLE FOEM'); // {submitGbtFrom: 'success'} 'SINGLE FOEM'
                console.log(a.submitGbtForm, 'SINGLE FOEM'); // undefined 'SINGLE FOEM'
                console.log(a["submitGbtForm"], 'SINGLE FOEM'); // undefined 'SINGLE FOEM'
              //  this.router.navigate(['/success/',this.ticketId]);
          },(err) =>  console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 1):

typo, not submitGbtForm, it should be submitGbtFrom